Compute the Rank as a Percentage in PieCloudDB
I have a Students table:



student_id
department_id
mark




4
2
608


2
2
500


8
2
608


7
1
618


11
1
580


1
1
620


3
1
593



I want to report the rank of each student in their department as a percentage, where the rank as a percentage is computed using the following formula: (student_rank_in_the_department - 1) * 100 / (number_of_students_in_the_department - 1). The percentage should be rounded to 2 decimal places. If two students get the same mark, they also get the same rank.
I tried the following in my PieCloudDB Database:
SELECT student_id ,department_id ,
COALESCE(ROUND((rk-1)*100.0/(cnt-1),2),0) percentage 
FROM(
SELECT student_id ,department_id ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY mark DESC) rk ,
COUNT(student_id) OVER (PARTITION BY department_id) cnt 
FROM Students 
) a
ORDER BY department_id;

and got the right results:



student_id
department_id
mark




1
1
0.00


7
1
33.33


3
1
66.67


11
1
100.00


4
2
0.00


8
2
0.00


2
2
100.00



I now learned that there is a function PERCENT_RANK() that can directly achieve my requirements, then I tried it:
SELECT student_id, department_id,
       ROUND((PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY mark DESC)) * 100, 2) AS percentage
FROM Students
ORDER BY department_id;

But I don't know why I got an ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist.

I looked through some documents, in PieCloudDB database, the parameter type in the ROUND() is numeric, after I convert the data type to numeric, it can be executed normally.
SELECT student_id, department_id,
       ROUND((PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY mark DESC))::numeric * 100, 2) AS percentage
FROM Students
ORDER BY department_id;

